# Function To Determine If Binary Tree Leaves Are Maxima In Path

Tags: java, python

I have a challenging task to solve. I've got a binary tree, like this one: the root is 11, the children of 11 are 5 and 8, the children of 5 are 13 and 12, the right child of 8 is 14.

I have to write a function that looks at all the leaves, and returns true, if the leaf is the maximum in the path leading from the root to the leaf, and false if that is not the case. So, e.g. for leaf 14, this is obviously true, because from the root (11), there is one node (5), and 14 is the maximum of these.

I know that this has to be a recursive function, but I don't really have an idea how to tackle this. An explanation in Python, Java, C or Pascal would be great, but I'd already be happy if someone could just give me a hint how to solve this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task very similar to [binary **search** tree verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Verification)

code in C from this article:

```
bool isBST(struct TreeNode *node, int minKey, int maxKey) {
  if(node == NULL) return true;
  if(node->key < minKey || node->key > maxKey) return false;
  return isBST(node->left, minKey, node->key-1) && isBST(node->right, node->key+1, maxKey);
}
```

search trees have abundant theory and bigger than single answer. You could go deeper if you want. Enjoy :)